# Sticky keys UI feedback

Tags: gui, accessibility

Is there any way of knowing which sticky key is active? In MS Windows, there is a small icon which is very useful in providing visual feedback of which key is sticky.

How can I have that visual feedback in Ubuntu 14.04 too?